# How to fix 'Unexpected value 'HttpClient' imported by the module 'AppModule' ' error in Angular application

Tags: angular

I am trying to set up a simple Angular ASP.NET Core web application. I followed the steps in the following link to set it up:

https://medium.com/@levifuller/building-an-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-visualized-f4b163830eaa

Now I am using Angular 7 where as the tutorial is written for Angular 4. As such some minor changes were needed. However, I haven't been able to get it to work, when I build the application I get a blank screen. In my browser I get the following error message:
Unexpected value 'HttpClient' imported by the module 'AppModule'.

I have tried looking up this error online, but I haven't been able to find an answer. I know that in Angular 7 I should import HttpClientModule and HttpClient instead of Http, but that seems to be in line with what people are saying.

This is my app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And this is my app.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this error from happening? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Everything looks good here, did you try clearing cache and running again?

Comment: if implements onInit you need defined the ngOnInit function. But I don't understand the error you get it :(

Comment: Hi Steve, every thing you did seems to be fine, try deleting node_modules and do npm install again, if that doesn't work clean your npm cache and try again

Comment: Thanks for the tips!
Upon trying to run npm install, I get some warnings, I think they might be causing the error in the application too. 
```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```
Any ideas how to resolve this? 

@Eliseo I do have an ngOnInit, I removed it in the original post because I didn't think it'd be relevant ;)

Comment: @Steve There is nothing to be fixed. The warning is just telling you that an *optional* dependency, that is thus not necessary, is not supported on your platform and is thus skipped. The error `Unexpected value 'HttpClient' imported by the module 'AppModule'` is most probably because the actual code that you're running is not the code you posted, and has `HttpClient` in the imports of AppModule instead of `HttpClientModule`.

Comment: @SteveAlberts Those warnings `npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 ` etc. are normal for those using windows. They just mean that npm is not installing dependencies required for `darwin` operating systems (e.g. a mac). You have a `win32` operating system so it doesn't need fs events.

Comment: Hi all, thanks very much for the tips! In the end, re-installing turned out to be sufficient. It didn't work before because I used the IIS Express button in Visual Studio, and it took a while before I realised that this did not yet rebuild the Angular code... novice mistake, I am really new at Angular ;) Thanks a lot for your help everyone!